# main wood floor unlevel

Tags: level

my house was completely remodeled about 8 yrs ago. a L beam was installed in basement with 2 house jacks as support.  The main wood floor was even, but as time had the house resettle the main floor is uneven.  The basement is finished and the jackets are enclosed in drywall.  What kind of professional do I need to get to level the floor, and repair any areas.

Comment: Contractors are often on the hook for major structural problems for 10 years. Do you have access to the remodeler? This could be a warranty or legal liability issue.

Answer (score 2):

8 years should not ordinarily result in a significant deflection of the floor unless there is a problem.  Figuring out the problem and how to correct it may involve several professionals, depending on exactly what is wrong and how much work you need to do: structural engineer, architect, soil testing, carpentry, painting, etc..., and you could wind up needing someone to manage insurance claims or deal with legal issues.  It may be as simple as having a GC replace a failing support or as complex as a major erosion problem or faulty building design.

The first thing to do is find a reliable general contractor and have them look at the house.  Before hiring anyone to do major work, talk to and get bids from multiple contractors.  The second contractor may realize something the first didn't, and competitive bids ordinarily save you a substantial percentage of the price.

Answer (score 0):

Before getting contractors in I would call your local inspector and ask them for the permits, who signed off on it, designs, whatever they have.

What you had done is pretty major.  As it is part of a remodel I think the chances of this not being directly correlated to the new L-beam is really small.  I wouldn't be worried about the 1-in-10000 issues until you proved that the jacks and beam were set right.

If this were my house I would open up the two ends of the L-beam so that we can see how it is setting, what it is setting on and where exactly it was notched in.  Also I would open the under side of the L-beam to investigate the current sag or differentiation.

If I were to just guess your L-beam was probably undersized or installed incorrectly.  if you are noticing the issue years later - anymore than 2-3 years than the beam was close to sufficient... but not quite there.  If your city has permits/plans you can see if it was installed right.  If it was installed right and is the right L-beam according to permits than it is on the architect (if no architect then the contractor).  If it is the wrong beam or installed wrong it is squarely on the contractor.

Even if your contractor no longer works in your area or exists these things need to be exposed before bringing in other contractors.  Without this they are just taking half-ass guesses, as I am right now.  I would say there is a 90%+ chance that you will need a better L-beam installed or it needs to be installed right.  I would also guess you could get your floor flat quickly by jacking the middle of the beam.  If you have pictures and more exacts I have beamed many a basement and can give you exact things to do.  Your issue is pretty common and you are probably looking at $500-1000 plus cost of new beam.